# Google Custom Search API - Inaccurate results

Tags: python, google-search

I'm trying to use the aforementioned API to get number of google search results for a query, however it's not giving me the correct results. I have my custom search engine configured to search the entire web. For example, if I search "hello" I get 113,000,000 results. However if I do that myself on Google I get 1,340,000,000. I'm quite new to all this stuff so feeling quite lost, can anybody please help? Thanks

```
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
import pprint

my_api_key = "API KEY"
my_cse_id = "CSE ID"

def main():
  service = build("customsearch", "v1",
            developerKey = my_api_key)

  res = service.cse().list(q = 'hello', cx= my_cse_id,).execute()
  pprint.pprint(res)

if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```